# "operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double' "

Tags: c#, asp.net

so i'm trying to write a method that looks at the selected items on a form and calculates the cost of a pizza. the variable is declare as type decimal but it is telling me i cannot use the += operator to add too the variable. however if i leave it as a decimal and just add whole numbers it allows it.

```
private decimal findTotal( )
    {
        decimal TotalDec = 0;

        //add size cost to total 
       if (sizeDDB .SelectedIndex == 0)
            TotalDec += 12;
        if (sizeDDB.SelectedIndex==1)  
            TotalDec += 14;
        if (sizeDDB.SelectedIndex == 2)
            TotalDec += 16;

        //add chrust cost
        if (crustDDB.SelectedIndex == 2)
            TotalDec += 2;

        // add topping cost
        if (sausageCB.Checked)
            TotalDec += 2;
        if (pepperoniCB.Checked)
            TotalDec += 1.5; //This is the line it doesn't like

        return TotalDec;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

```
TotalDec += 1.5m;
```

Comment: it worked. does it just assume its a float without the 'm'?

Comment: @Roger: Yes. C# needs to validate the literal 1.5 -> double, 1.5m -> decimal.

Comment: @Roger - a `float` would be `1.5f`. Just `1.5` is a double.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast

```
private decimal findTotal( )
{
    decimal TotalDec = 0;

    //add size cost to total 
   if (sizeDDB .SelectedIndex == 0)
        TotalDec += 12;
    if (sizeDDB.SelectedIndex==1)  
        TotalDec += 14;
    if (sizeDDB.SelectedIndex == 2)
        TotalDec += 16;

    //add chrust cost
    if (crustDDB.SelectedIndex == 2)
        TotalDec += 2;

    // add topping cost
    if (sausageCB.Checked)
        TotalDec += 2;
    if (pepperoniCB.Checked)
        TotalDec += (decimal)1.5; //there is no automatic casting from double to decimal, so you have to do it manually like this
    return TotalDec;
}
```

Comment: Or define the literal as decimal (`TotalDec += 1.5m`). See [decimal (C# reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/364x0z75.aspx) for details.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Yeah, this also work, Good suggestion :)